# Problem with C# script Interstitial banner Admob Unexpected symbol

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm having problem while compiling my Unity3d game.

I've written a C# script for show Interstitial Banners with Admob.

The compiler throws me this error:

> Assets/MostrarIntersticial.cs(6,8): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol
>   'InterstitialAd', expecting 'class', 'delegate', 'enum', 'interface',
>   'partial', or 'struct'

This is the code of the Script that shows the Admob Interstitial Ad (Full Screen Ad)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

private InterstitialAd interstitial;

public class MostrarIntersticial : MonoBehaviour {

    // Inicialización del intersticial
    private void Start () {
          #if UNITY_ANDROID
             string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
         #elif UNITY_IPHONE
             string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
         #else
             string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
         #endif



      //Inicializar intersticial:
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
      // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
      // Load the interstitial with the request.
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);   
}
      private void showAdMob() {
            if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
                this.interstitial.Show();
                }
    }  

//Muestra un mensaje al fallar la carga del interstitial
    public void fallaAlCargar(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args) {

        print("Interstitial failed to load: " + args.Message);
  // Handle the ad failed to load event.
};

interstitial.Destroy();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the line `private InterstitialAd interstitial;` in your class not outside it:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

    public class MostrarIntersticial : MonoBehaviour {

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

        // Inicialización del intersticial
        private void Start () {

              #if UNITY_ANDROID
                 string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
             #elif UNITY_IPHONE
                 string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
             #else
                 string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
             #endif

// rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you Dave !! I don't now how I didn't see that ! :)

Comment: No problem @MauroStancato, mark it as answer if it helped you.